# Shapes.AddPicture (msoFalse) - Not Defined

Tags: vb.net

I have code in VB.NET which tries to add an image to Excel and save it. There is a problem when I am calling `Shapes.AddPicture`.

```
objWorkSheet.Shapes.AddPicture("c:\BLABLABLA", msoFalse, 10, 436, 515)
```

The problem is when I write `msoFalse` or something familiar with `MsoTriState` it gives me an error that it is not declared.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: It is an enum member, so you must spell it MsoTriState.msoFalse.  Ensure that Imports Microsoft.Office.Core is at the top of the source file.

Comment: Hans - When I write Imports Microsoft.Office.Core it gives me an error that this import statement is unnecesery. But also when I try to put MsoTriState.msoFalse it gives me the same error as before. Is there something missing from my code or what?

Comment: Hmm, that never produces an "error".  I can't see your screen from here.

Comment: i found this: Shapes.AddPicture(String, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState, Single, Single, Single, Single) As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shape 
but when i write Microsoft.Office.Core it gives me an error that "core is not a member of Microsoft.Office"

Comment: Remove the reference to Excel and add it back.  Should fix the problem, use Project > Properties > References to verify that Microsoft.Office.Core got added as well

Comment: Got it... had to add reference in COM tab -> Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library 
Thank you very much Hans Passant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a missing reference of "Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library". In my case i put version 15.0

Step 1: Right-click your project

Step 2: Select "Add reference.."

Step 3: Click on the "COM" tab

Step 4: Scroll down to select "Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library".